# Redirecting to HTML page from AJAX response sent from Node server

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

From my Webpage I send an AJAX Post request :

```
 $.ajax({
        url:"/test",
        type:"POST",
        data:{"final":data},
        dataType   : "json",
        success    : function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function (data) {
            console.log(data);

        }
    });
```

Which reached my express route:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log("reached post") 
  //business logic
 res.render(path.join(__dirname+'/../views/index'), {data: body1});

});
```

But if Im not wrong, my view HTML response will be returned to the AJAX call which will not be rendered in the browser. How do I go about rendering this response ? Or is there any other method to do this?

Comment: you are using `ajax` dataType as `JSON` so you should return `json` object back to `ajax` request, using `res.json(object)`

Comment: okay. But what I want to do is redirect to a new page after the POST request. How can I do this?

Comment: send response back as `json` response then you can `catch data`  inside `success` function and redirect using `window.location.href=PAGE_URL`

Comment: I need to send data along with my html page. As you see in my res.render, I am sending data along with index.

Comment: use node file system `fs.readFile` to read file first and send it back to your ajax request as `json` or use `dataType:"html"` in your ajax code if you are not able to send it as `json`